# Choropleth - JS issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, choropleth

I am trying to draw a choropleth using d3. My GeoJSON feature header looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "GEO_ID": "0500000US01029",
          "STATE": "01",
          "COUNTY": "029",
          "NAME": "Cleburne",
          "LSAD": "County",
          "CENSUSAREA": 560.100000
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
              [
                [-85.388717, 33.913044],
                [-85.380885, 33.873508],
                [-85.379455, 33.866291],
                [-85.377426, 33.856047],
                [-85.376403, 33.850656],
                [-85.364595, 33.788446],
                [-85.361844, 33.773951],
                [-85.360491, 33.767958],
                [-85.357402, 33.750104],
                [-85.355252, 33.739245],
                [-85.344054,
```

I tried following Gordon's fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/28qsa0jr/7/) - I pulled down the Iowa GEOJson data and built a fiddle with Gordon's Iowa population data.  https://jsfiddle.net/akpjsfiddle/2m0npm91/3/

My choropleth does not render. I tried checking for any mismatched parentheses - I didn't find any. Perhaps the issue is how I've coded the binding? Any help or pointers, please?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your fiddle, the chart is being rendered. What is your problem?

Comment: Indeed - it works! I think the issues stem from me not refreshing the code post changes. Thanks for help.